# Delete Wildcard Row in Azure Table Without Query

Tags: linq, azure-table-storage

Is there a simple way to delete rows in Azure Table Storage without Query,

for example, if I want to delete any row that `PartitionKey="A"` without get all content back and delete one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is "no way" *for now*. If you only have PartitionKey or RowKey, you have to read all back then delete one by one :(

Answer (score 1):

The REST API supports this (using If-Match:*): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd135727.aspx
Not sure the managed API supports this. You might be able to "trick" the managed API by registering a SendRequestEvent handler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.sendingrequest.aspx) and have that one change the If-Match header. I have not tested that.

Comment: Hm, I realize I might have misunderstood what you want to do. You don't even wnat to know how many entities there are in partition A, right? The "Etag fix" would only work if you new partition key and row key... If you only have the partition key I'm afraid you must read all entities first.