# Azure Tables delete and create table fails

Tags: java, azure, azure-table-storage

My problem is that from time to time I want to delete the **contents** of an Azure table from Java. The table has millions of rows so it didn't seem like a good method to delete all entities one by one (because of the many REST API calls).

I tried to delete and then create the table again, but my code fails.

```
getTableClient().deleteTableIfExists("tablename");
getTableClient().createTableIfNotExists("tablename");
```

Here is my stacktrace:

```
com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableServiceException: Conflict
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableServiceException.generateTableServiceException(TableServiceException.java:57)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableOperation$2.execute(TableOperation.java:339)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableOperation$2.execute(TableOperation.java:322)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.core.storage.utils.implementation.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:110)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableOperation.performInsert(TableOperation.java:374)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.TableOperation.execute(TableOperation.java:551)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTableClient.execute(CloudTableClient.java:638)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTableClient.createTable(CloudTableClient.java:173)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTableClient.createTableIfNotExists(CloudTableClient.java:251)
at com.microsoft.windowsazure.services.table.client.CloudTableClient.createTableIfNotExists(CloudTableClient.java:197)
```

Do I have to sleep for a while between to two calls? I would rather not have too long wait here because I want to make this operation as short as possible so other threads can write again in the table.

Or is there a safe way to do this?

---

**Edit**

Yes, I am looking for an equivalent of the SQL statement: `DELETE FROM tablename;` in Azure Tables with as few REST API calls as possible.

My current best shot is:

```
getTableClient().deleteTableIfExists("tablename");
// TODO: solve problem with new creation!
boolean success = false;
while (!success) {
try {
  success = getTableClient().createTableIfNotExists("tablename");
} catch (StorageException e) {
  System.err.println("Log table recreation failed retrying in 5 sec");
  try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
}
```

I am looking for a better and safer solution then this!

Comment: No you are looking for SQL Drop Table.  You don't want delete by entity (row) as that could be multiple (billed) transactions.  Delete table is one transaction.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The delete operation against a Windows Azure table is not an instant operation.  When the delete request is issued, it is marked for deletion by the storage service and no longer accessible by clients.  The table is then deleted (garbage collected) in the background.  This could take a few seconds to complete.

You're getting a 409 (Conflict) because the table still exists when the code requests a new table be created of the same name.

See the Remarks section (bottom of the page) of the MSDN document at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179387.aspx.

Other than waiting (like you have done) or creating a table with a different name, I'm not aware of an alternative.

Comment: This is most likely what is happening.  You should actually get an error message on the wire that says the table is being deleted as well.  You would see it in a .NET client in the exception, not sure why you don't see it in Java client.  Also, it can take many *minutes* (as opposed to seconds) for large tables to be garbage collected.  I have seen upwards of 40 mins in some cases for very large tables.

Answer (score 2):

@mcollier is correct as to the cause here, but I wanted to point out a possible solution.  Whenever we are faced with a scenario where we know we are going to have lots of table data that we want to prune occasionally, we design around it by rolling our tables.  So, on a periodic basis we either increment the tablename or put the date in it for daily data (e.g. logs20120628).  Then we can delete the entire table whenever we don't need that data anymore without impacting the current table or being forced to wait (sometimes very long waits) until we can recreate the table.

Just design a little flexibility into your table naming and this won't be a big issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you use one delete REST call to [delete a table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179387.aspx)?

Comment: I do use one call to delete the table... And another to add it again.As @Will pointed out my goal is to delete all data FROM the table. Which has no equivalent in the azure tables API.

Comment: ah i see i misinterpreted your question, looks like its not possible atm, maybe update this answer one day when it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You want the equiv of the SQL `DELETE FROM table;` or `TRUNCATE TABLE table;`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8920072/15721 says there's no way to this :(

Comment: That is exactly what I want to do. That is why I am deleting and recreating the table. What I don't understand is why I get a conflict while executing these sequentially.